# Find the conditional expectation of two correlated standard normal

Tags: probability

Suppose $X, Y \sim N(0,1)$ and the covariance matrix of them is $\begin{bmatrix}1 & \rho \\ \rho & 1\end{bmatrix}$. Find $E(X|Y > 0)$.
Any thought on this question?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/356023/expectation-of-truncated-normal/

Answer (score 0):

Just to get you started.

By definition,

$$E[X\mid Y>0]=\frac{E[X\mathbf1_{Y>0}]}{P(Y>0)}=\frac{1}{P(Y>0)}\iint x\mathbf1_{y>0} f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,dx\,dy$$

You can see this from the conditional density of $X$ given that $Y>0$:

$$f_{X\mid Y>0}(x)=\int_0^\infty \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{P(Y>0)}\,dy\qquad,\,x\in\mathbb R$$

Therefore, $$E[X\mid Y>0]=\int xf_{X\mid Y>0}(x)\,dx$$

---

You can check your final answer in [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/356023/expectation-of-truncated-normal/) thread on *CrossValidated*.